# Store a function variable's value to use it again next time function is called

Tags: python, pywin32

I have a function that determines which Excel row to highlight.  But I only want one row to be highlighted at a time.  So, when the function is called again, I want it to remove the previous row's highlighting (i.e., highlight it white), and highlight the new row.

I could just have the function highlight the whole sheet white each time it's called.  But I don't really want to do that just in case a user has other rows they already highlighted.

Here's the function I have that's being called:

```
def highlightSol(self, id):        
    for row, cell in enumerate(self.xl.ActiveSheet.Range('A:A')):
        if id == cell:
            row = self.row + 1
            self.xl.ActiveSheet.Cells(row,1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 1
```

This works to highlight the row.  But I'd like the value of row to remain somehow so that when this function is called again, I can unhighlight that row (or, technically, highlight it another color).

This is probably pretty easy but for some reason I'm stuck thinking of a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks!

Comment: What do `self.x1` and `self.row` refer to?  How about storing the old row in `self.old_row`?  Or is `self` itself transient?  We need to know more about the class where this method is defined.  If this method is used by various objects, can you save this row id as a class attribute (which all the class instances share)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an attribute for the last highlighted element: `self.highlightRow = row`

You could set the attribute to `None` in your class's `__init__`. It is then just a matter of reading that attribute and un-highlighting that row.